# Python/Creating a graph in Sage Notebook

Tags: python, graph, sage

```
import csv

a = csv.reader(open(DATA+'DataA.csv'))

for row in a:
   time = row[1]
   conversion = row[3]
   x_series = time
   y_series = conversion
   scatter_plot(zip(x_series,y_series))
```

I am attempting to create a scatter plot in Sage Notebook. I'm reading in the data in DataA.csv specifically rows 1 and 3. I want to create a scatter plot based on those pieces of data. Everything works except that a new scatter plot is created for each individual tuple instead of having all of them on one scatter plot.
Any ideas of how I can fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this.

```
import csv

a = csv.reader(open(DATA+'DataA.csv'))

G = Graphics()

for row in a:
   time = row[1]
   conversion = row[3]
   x_series = time
   y_series = conversion
   G += scatter_plot(zip(x_series,y_series))

G # this will show the plot
```

I don't have your data (or any data, actually) so I can't test it, but this should work fine.  In Sage one adds plots, and then they show up as the default representation when `G` is given.  You could ask the different scatter plots to have different colors, too...

Also, I prefer to use [point](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/point.html#sage.plot.point.point) or perhaps `list_plot` for this, but I guess it's a matter of preference.